# Пропало содержимое файла в phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm

Всем привет.

Сидел работал над классом обработки входящих данных для сайта, в PhpStorm, выключился комп (как я понял, из-за перегрева).

Включил комп, запустил PhpStorm, вижу, как сбросились настройки подсветки - вернул настройки.
Вижу, что нету моего проекта - открыл проект заново (File->Open Dir).
Открываю файл с классом, над которым работал в момент выключения, - там пусто. Времени потрачено на его написание приличное, и меня тут же переполнили смешанные чувства.

Может, PhpStorm хранит какие-то кеши/темпы/бекапы того, с чем я работаю в текущий момент? Есть возможность восстановить то, что мистическим образом сгинуло в никуда?

Comment: @Coolmac, шторм сохраняет все в момент потери фокуса окна и ничего не кэширует, насколько знаю.

Comment: Это ладно, а почему файл то пустой? Я сохраняю чуть ли ни каждые пол строчки рефлекторно, не задумываясь.

Comment: Нажмите ``Alt-` -> Show History`` и посмотрите историю, может что-то найдется.

Comment: Спасибо, смотрел... Пусто.